# Can the powers of $2$ in the denominators of a fraction sum be used to find a contradiction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, fractions

Let $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2, d_1, d_2, e_1, e_2$ be odd integers, with
$$\gcd(a_1,a_2)=\gcd(b_1,b_2)=\gcd(c_1,c_2)=\gcd(d_1,d_2)=\gcd(e_1,e_2)=1,$$
and assume $n \ge 3$ and $m \ge 1$ are integers such that
$$
\frac{a_1}{2^{3(n-1)m}a_2} + \frac{b_1}{2^{3\left((n-1)m+1\right)}b_2} + \frac{c_1}{2^{3\left((n-1)m+1\right)}c_2} + \frac{d_1}{2^{3nm}d_2} + \frac{e_1}{2^{3nm}e_2} = 1.  \tag{$\star$}
$$

Is there a way to prove, using only the powers of $2$ in the set of denominators, that ($\star$) is impossible?

Comment: Oops! Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it stands now, $(\star)$ is obviously possible. Let $n=3,m=2$. Then the denominators of five fractions contain (correspondingly, in the same order) $2^{12}, 2^{15}, 2^{15}, 2^{18},\text{ and }2^{18}$. Now,
$$
{184313\over45\cdot2^{12}} + {1\over9\cdot2^{15}} + {1\over1\cdot2^{15}} + {1\over15\cdot2^{18}} + {1\over1\cdot2^{18}}=\dots
$$
...guess what?